# when I click button in collection view, i I can't pass value to next view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, collectionview

I had encounter a question. I used collection view set more button. I need click button and passs index value to "NextViewController". But when I click the button. It is show below error message.

I try to find where's error. But I can't find.

Have any one can give me some hint?

thank you very much.

==========**error message** ===========

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-    [UIViewController
>   itemsArray:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance     0x9e78220'

===================================

=========== **ListViewController.m**==========

```
@interface ListViewController ()
{
    NSMutableArray * itemsArray ;

}
end
...
...  //itemsArray had some data from webesrvice
...
-(UICollectionViewCell*) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView     cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

CustomizedCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CustomizedCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
 NSInteger targetIndex = indexPath.row + indexPath.section*3;

if( targetIndex < itemsArray.count )
{

        [cell.cateBtn setTitle:[[itemsArray objectAtIndex:targetIndex] itemName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            cell.cateBtn.tag = targetIndex;
            [cell.cateBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(jumpToNextView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];
            return cell;
}

-(void)jumpToNextView:(UIButton*)sender
{

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySegueName" sender:sender];
}
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{


    NextViewController *nextViewController =        
          segue.destinationViewController;
       nextViewController. itemsArray = itemsArray;
}

-(BOOL) shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
{


    if( targetIndex < itemsArray.count )
         return YES;
     else
         return NO;
}
```

========== **NextViewController.h** =========

```
@interface NextViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *itemsArray;
@end
```

Comment: Could it be that your segue.destinationViewController is not really of type NextViewController? I'm not sure what could happen if that was the case but i assume segue.destinationViewController returns id so the assignment is done even if it's not the correct type?

Comment: Either way the problem seems to be the assignment of items array to your nextViewController. Turn on exception breakpoints to check.

Comment: You should remove the brackets ( '{' and '}' ) in your nextViewController's header, not sure that your syntax works.

Comment: Is the `segue.destinationViewController` a `UINavigationController` by any chance? You could add a breakpoint to find out.

Comment: @JoeFryer the exception clearly states its a UIViewController. But you right he should ad a exception breakpoint.

Comment: My bad. Note to self - read the question.

Comment: check the class name for NextViewController in storyboard. it should be NextViewController. but as i can see in crash log class name is UIViewController & UIViewController has nothing like itemsArray.

Comment: and where is `jumpToNextView:` method implementation?

Comment: sorry ~! I post have some mistakes. I had fix the content. thanks

Comment: The problem is happened on "nextViewController. itemsArray = itemsArray;" If I comment this line. There are not crash. But I don't know whats happend on here . thanks.

Comment: I had solved the problem~~ I appreciate for everyone especially @pawan. The problem is my storyboard class name not set NextViewController. Thank you very much~!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the class name for `NextViewController` in `storyboard`. it should be `NextViewController`. but as

> i can see in crash log class name is UIViewController & UIViewController has nothing like itemsArray.

thats the reason you are getting crash here.

modify this

```
 [cell.cateBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(jumpToNextView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];
```

with

```
 [cell.cateBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(jumpToDrScheduleList:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

selector for button & event to UIControlEventTouchUpInside;

Comment: I had solved the problem.  The problem is my storyboard class name not set NextViewController. Thank @pawan very much~!

Answer (score 1):

I guess the Problem is with your button Action method name: `jumpToNextView` 
in this line:

```
        [cell.cateBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(jumpToNextView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];
```

Rather Change `jumpToDrScheduleList:` in selector or Change Method name.

```
-(void)jumpToNextView:(UIButton*)sender
{

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySegueName" sender:sender];
}
```

Comment: looks like he just forgot to post `jumpToNextView:` implementation, cuz if add wrong selector to `cateBtn` he would get another exception

Comment: yap. I'm not changed to jumpToNextView name. sorry~

Comment: no, I'm not solved my problem. It just method name not changed when I post the question. I am try to find answer. thanks .

Comment: Thank you, @user203108,@ Mykola Denysyuk .  I had solved my problem.The answer is I had not set class name in storyboard.